# How can I improve the accuracy of this keras Neural Network?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, python-3.6

I'm working with the [Heart Disease](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Heart+Disease) dataset from Machine Learning Repository and I want to improve the accuracy 0.8533 of my NN.

I've tried many things and I got the best results with this settings

```
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Dense(units = 16, activation = 'relu', 
                        kernel_initializer = 'normal', input_dim = 13))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.2))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 8, activation = 'relu',
                        kernel_initializer = 'normal'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.2))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
                      metrics = ['accuracy'])

classifier.fit(x = attributes, y = classes, batch_size = 1, epochs = 1000,
                  validation_split = 0.25)
```

I've changes the number of nodes to 10 and 5, respectively, changed the optimizer to rmsprop and sgd, changed the kernel_initializer to 'normal' and 'random_uniform'. Even though, the accuracy hasn't improved.

What tips could you guys give me to make the accuracy higher?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have overfitting try reducing the Dropout rate. Have you studied the dataset? Maybe there are unnecesary features and you can reduce dimensionality with PCA for example. Try using K-Fold with your dataset to get a more realisting accuracy. Have you tried other classifiers? Neural Networks are very cool but sometimes SVM, LR, RandomForest, XGBoost work pretty decently and are easier to tune if you use a Grid with sklearn. Good luck!